# Fastest way to snap two faces together by aligning their centers in non-standard orientations?

Tags: snapping

In the attached example, I moved the origins of the two shapes to the center of the desired faces.

The objective is to snap the cube's face (where the origin is moved to) to the slanted face. Basically snap origin to origin by aligning the cube to the orientation of slanted face.

[image]
[image]

Arbitrary orientation
[image]

Comment: If you enable the snapping option called "Align Rotation With The Snapping Target" it should work

Comment: It doesn't snap origin to origin.

Comment: are you trying to do it with snap or any way will be good?

Comment: Hopefully a way with the least steps, keeping in mind that in cad software this and other snapping, is trivial.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282835/142292

Answer (score 1):

When you have the two objects with the origins in the same location, activate snap vertex option, select the object that needs to rotate and press R, searching for a vertex of the angled face.

If the rotation is not aligned with a view, use custom orientations, and press R followed by the choosen axis twice (i.e. R,X,X will rotate around X local axis).

[image]

Comment: This one gets close. The issue is If the rotation is not aligned with a view, then I am having one hell of a time.

Answer (score 0):

Select the static one first, then hit shift+s>>cursor to selected then select the another one and hit shift+s>> selection to cursor, then use the "Align Rotation With The Snapping Target". I use this tools so many time, I made hotkeys for the mouse 4-5 buttons, combined with shit and ctrl, I recommend the hotkeys to you too.

"Align Rotation With The Snapping Target" means the "Align Rotation With The Snapping Target":
[image]

Comment: So far I have the two origins touching (after selection to cursor) .. but then how did you do "Align Rotation With The Snapping Target" ? If you mean the snapping option, it doesn't work because with this method we snap an object to the cursor, not to another object (so there is nothing to orient to).